# In OCaml, how to predicate a variable is a List?

Tags: list, ocaml, predicate

For example,

`let x = ["a";"b";"c";"d"];;`

`let listp = 
    if (x.isa(List)) then true else false;;`

Is there something like a "isa" method in OCaml to predicate a variable is a List/Array/Tuple... and so on?

Answer (score 4):

OCaml has no constructs for testing the type of something. A good rule of thumb is that types are either fixed or are completely unknown. In the first case, there's no need to test. In the second case, the code is required to work for all possible types.

This works out a lot better than you might expect if you're used to other languages. It's kind of a nice application of the [zero/one/infinity rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule).

Note that there is no trouble defining a type that contains one of a set of types you are interested in:

```
type number = MyFloat of float | MyInt of int
```

Values of this type look like: `MyFloat 3.1` or `MyInt 30281`. You can, in effect, test the type by matching against the constructor:

```
let is_int x = match x with MyFloat _ -> false | MyInt _ -> true
```

The same is true for lists and arrays, except that these are parameterized types:

```
type 'a collection = MyArray of 'a array | MyList of 'a list


let is_list x = match x with MyArray _ -> false | MyList _ -> true
```

What you get back for the lack of so-called introspection is that you can easily construct and deconstruct values with rich and expressive types, and you can be assured that functions you call can't mess with a value when they don't know what its type is.

Comment: @nuk this "no" answer is a good first approximation, but there are nuances related to (1) subtyping for objects and polymorphic variants and (2) GADTs, which might give you a cautious "yes" answer in a particular context.

Comment: For example, with GADTs, you can provide a value that describes the type of another value, in a way that allows to perform type-specific manipulations safely. But this is cumbersome, you almost surely don't need it.

Comment: This is true, but I thought it would be best to start with the simplest description.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I think your choice of constructors name is very poor, it can be very confusing, one might think that he has to name them this way, with the type of the value. Plus, I don't like the "test the type by matching". You're not testing the type, the type is "number". You can totally have different constructors which use the same types.

Comment: I'll change constructor names, it could be clearer to use names that are more clearly not predefined. Whether you're testing the type or not is mostly a matter of nomenclature IMHO. This is why I say "in effect". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just `match x with` something specific to your type? For example, for a sequence:

```
let listp = match x with | h::t -> true | _ -> false
```

for a tuple, I don't remember the exact syntax, but something like `match x with | (k,v) -> true`

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Not really: everything has a type associated with it, so either it's already known that it's a list, or it's polymorphic (like `'a`), in which case we're not "allowed" to know about the underlying type. Doing anything type-specific in that case would force specialization of the value's type.